# Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Okay so I'm having some major problems here. I'm recreating my discord bot by moving any modules (counting, url filter, etc) into its own files. For some reason, I keep getting `Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined`. I tried several things and I can't figure it out. Here is what my code looks like:

**greenfox.js** (Main file)

```js
//Preload constants and configs
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token, devmode } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.mods = new Discord.Collection();
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

//Logging Utility
const myLoggers = require('log4js');
myLoggers.configure({
    appenders: {
        mylogger: {
            type: "file",
            filename: "./error.log"
        }
    },
    categories: {
        default: {
            appenders: ["mylogger"],
            level: "ALL"
        }
    }
});
myLoggers.configure({
    appenders: {
        msglogger: {
            type: "file",
            filename: "./messages.log"
        }
    },
    categories: {
        default: {
            appenders: ["msglogger"],
            level: "ALL"
        }
    }
});
const logger = myLoggers.getLogger("mylogger");
const msglogger = myLoggers.getLogger("msglogger");

//Locate and load command files
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    console.log(`\x1b[32m[Command Loaded] \x1b[0m${prefix}${command.name} from ./commands/${file}`);
}

//Locate and load modules
const modFiles = fs.readdirSync('./modules').filter(file2 => file2.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file2 of modFiles) {
    const mod = require(`./modules/${file2}`);
    client.mods.set(mod.name, mod);
    console.log(`\x1b[32m[Module Loaded] \x1b[0m${mod.name} from ./modules/${file2}`);
}

//Check to see if a user ran a command
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;


    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
        //If command failed to run, notify user and log error to error log file
    } catch (error) {
        logger.debug(error);
        console.log(`\x1b[31m[Failed Command] \x1b[0m${message.content} ran from ${message.guild.name} (ID: ${message.guild.id}) by ${message.author.tag} (ID: ${message.author.id}). Check the error log for details`);
        message.channel.send('there was an error trying to execute that command! Details: \`\`\`js\n' + (error) + '\`\`\`');
    }

});
//Check to see if a user ran a module
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    const mod = message.content;
    console.log(`trying ${mod.name}`);
//  console.log(message.content);
    client.mods.get(mod).execute(message);


//  if (!client.mods.has(mod)) return;
//    try {
//        client.mods.get(mod).execute(message);
//      console.log(`trying ${mod}`);
        //If module failed to run, notify user and log error to error log file
//    } catch (error) {
//        logger.debug(error);
//        console.log(`\x1b[31m[Failed Module] \x1b[0m${message.content} ran from ${message.guild.name} (ID: ${message.guild.id}) by ${message.author.tag} (ID: ${message.author.id}). Check the error log for details`);
//        message.channel.send(`there was an error trying to execute that module (${mod})! Details: \`\`\`js\n` + (error) + `\`\`\``);
//    }
});

//Start bot on clients
client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(`Online and functioning!`);
    //Check if development mode is set to true. if it's true, set status to notify user of possible errors
    if (devmode === "true") {
        client.user.setActivity(`Bot is in development mode. Some commands may not function correctly.`);
        console.log(`\x1b[36m[Info] \x1b[0mBot is in development mode. If this was a mistake, stop the bot and edit the configuration file.`);
    }

});


client.login(token);
```

**counting.js** Example module file located at `modules/counting.js`

```js
module.exports = {
        name: 'Counting challenge',
        execute(message) {
//Start of module
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.channel.id === '716102493171613706') {
if (isNaN(message.content)) return;
if(message.type === "PINS_ADD") return;
        var currentnumber = fs.readFileSync("counting.num.txt", "utf8");
        var currentuser = fs.readFileSync("counting.usr.txt", "utf8");
        if (currentnumber === message.content) {
                if (currentuser === message.author.id) {
                        message.channel.send(`${message.author} RUINED IT AT ${currentnumber}! You cannot count twice in a row! The next number is 0`);
                        fs.writeFile("counting.num.txt", "0", function (err) {
                                if (err) return console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                var currentnumber = parseInt(currentnumber);
                var currentnumber = (currentnumber+1);
                fs.writeFile("counting.num.txt", `${currentnumber}`, function (err) {
                                if (err) return console.log(err);
                        });
                fs.writeFile("counting.usr.txt", `${message.author.id}`, function (err) {
                                if (err) return console.log(err);
                        });
                message.react("");
                }
        } else {
                message.channel.send(`${message.author} RUINED IT AT ${currentnumber}! That was the wrong number! The next number is 0!`);
                fs.writeFile("counting.num.txt", "0", function (err) {
                                if (err) return console.log(err);
                });
        }
}
});
//End of module
        },
};
```

I did as much research as I possibly could and cannot find an answer. Commands are working normally, but not the modules. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the `client.mods` map has the `mod` key before calling the `execute` method on `client.mods.get(mod)` (your commented code does perform the check).

```js
const mod = message.content
if (!client.mods.has(mod)) {
  return
}
client.mods.get(mod).execute(message)
```

Comment: Okay I did that, but now I'm getting no output. For instance, I type the next number, and nothing happens, almost as if it doesn't call any modules.

Comment: @GreenFoxProductions Well, if the message doesn't exist in the `client.mods` map, nothing will happen since we return early. (Not sure what you're referring to by "the next number" though since the keys (module names) are strings).

Comment: Is there a way to loop through it? There's several files linked to the client.mods map.

Comment: @GreenFoxProductions The `client.mods` map is constructed with all the module names as keys. If the user message doesn't exist in the map, send the user a message with the available module names and ask them to use one of them. You could lowercase the module name before adding it to the map ` client.mods.set(mod.name.toLowerCase(), mod)`.

Comment: That's not what I want. Is there a way to search each module instead? My main priority is to reduce spaghetti code as there's several modules, and I don't want to write constants for each file.

Comment: @GreenFoxProductions Not sure what you mean. With your current code, if the user types 'Counting challenge', the `execute` method of `modules/counting.js` should run. You could set single-word module names, use `client.mods.set(mod.name.toLowerCase(), mod)` to add the module to the map, and lowercase the user's message before checking if it's in the map.